# Store api response to an array using react useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react hooks. I am trying to cast API response into an array using react `useState` hook. It's giving me empty with the below approach

```
const [post, setPostArray] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const postparams = { userList: result };
  axios
    .get(environment._urlPosts, { headers, params: postparams })
    .then(posts => {
      // storing response data in array
      setPostArray(posts.data.post);

      console.log(post);
    })
    .catch(err => {});
}, []);
```

Then I used the below approach and I was able to see data is printing in the console log

```
axios.get(environment._urlPosts, { headers, params: postparams }).then(posts => {
  // storing response data in array
  for (let obj of posts.data.post) {
      post.push(obj)
  }
  setPostArray(post)
  console.log(post)
```

But when I try to iterate this post array in my JSX, it's giving me empty array.

```
  </div>
{/* array length */}
        {post.length}

        {post.map(post =>
            <div className="card">
                <Post username={post.username} fullname={post.fullname} postedTime={post.postedTime} postContent='Hi' tweeterLike={post.tweeterLike} />
            </div>
        )}
```

Can you please help me to resolve this?

Comment: Since setState work like an async function you will not get the post state right after your set it. but you should be able to get that in the JSX

Comment: yeah 1st approach worked with JSX. Thanks.

Comment: Actually ur 1st comment resolved my problem. But anyway I accepted the provided answer also :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a minimal Example of what you are trying to achieve.
This is the working code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [post, setPostArray] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json);
      setPostArray([json]);
  })
    //  setPostArray([{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'},{name: 'c'}])
},[])

console.log(post)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {
        post.map(item => <div>{item.title} </div>)
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Here is the link to the example in codeSandBox**: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-snow-773kp